# Why does XNA's ContentManager follow generic type parameters for serialization purposes?

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline, xml, serialization

I've finally gotten to the bottom of a problem and am wondering what my best recourse is. In short, the problem is that XNA's `ReflectiveReader` reflects into generic type parameters, even if no instance of that generic type is stored in the object being serialized.

An example best demonstrates this. Consider the following model classes:

```
namespace Model
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

    public abstract class Entity
    {
    }

    public sealed class TestEntity : Entity
    {
        public Texture2D Texture
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public abstract class EntityData
    {
    }

    public abstract class EntityData<TData, TEntity> : EntityData
        where TData : EntityData
        where TEntity : Entity
    {
    }

    public sealed class TestEntityData : EntityData<TestEntityData, TestEntity>
    {
    }

    public sealed class LevelData
    {
        public List<EntityData> Entities
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose I want to define an instance of LevelData inside an XML file to be later loaded with the `ContentManager` (*Test.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent xmlns:Model="Model">
  <Asset Type="Model:LevelData">
    <Entities>
      <Item Type="Model:TestEntityData">
      </Item>
    </Entities>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

Now consider this simple load logic:

```
Content.Load<LevelData>("Test");
Content.Load<Texture2D>("Texture");
```

The first line succeeds, but the second throws an exception:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException was unhandled
  Message=Error loading "Texture". ContentTypeReader Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Texture2DReader, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553 conflicts with existing handler Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ReflectiveReader`1[[Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553]], Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553 for type Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.
  Source=Microsoft.Xna.Framework
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentTypeReaderManager.AddTypeReader(String readerTypeName, ContentReader contentReader, ContentTypeReader reader)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentTypeReaderManager.GetTypeReader(String readerTypeName, ContentReader contentReader, List`1& newTypeReaders)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentTypeReaderManager.ReadTypeManifest(Int32 typeCount, ContentReader contentReader)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadHeader()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentReader.ReadAsset[T]()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T](String assetName, Action`1 recordDisposableObject)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName)
       at XnaContentManagerRepro.Game1.LoadContent() in D:\Temp\XnaContentManagerRepro\XnaContentManagerRepro\XnaContentManagerRepro\Game1.cs:line 53
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Initialize()
       at XnaContentManagerRepro.Game1.Initialize() in D:\Temp\XnaContentManagerRepro\XnaContentManagerRepro\XnaContentManagerRepro\Game1.cs:line 39
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at XnaContentManagerRepro.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Temp\XnaContentManagerRepro\XnaContentManagerRepro\XnaContentManagerRepro\Program.cs:line 15
  InnerException:
```

If I set a breakpoint on the line that loads the texture and then examine the `ContentTypeReaderManager.nameToReader` member, I see this:

[image]

As you can see, a `ReflectiveReader` is indeed being mapped for the `Texture2D` type. This stems from my `TestEntity` class (see the the entries above the one highlighted in the image above). But if you examine my model classes, nothing hanging off `LevelData` has an instance of `TestEntity` or even `Entity` in it!

If I change the `TestEntityData` class to this:

```
public sealed class TestEntityData : EntityData<TestEntityData, Entity>
{
}
```

The exception no longer occurs. That's because `TestEntity` is never considered, so neither is `Texture2D`. Thus, the `ReflectiveReader` is looking at - and following - the generic type parameters in my model classes! I can only assume this is a bug - it makes no sense at all to me why this would be necessary.

My model classes have these generic type parameters for a good reason - they make my model code much simpler. Am I stuck here? Is my only option to refactor my models to never have a generic type parameter of my entity types? I considered using `ContentSerializerIgnoreAttribute`, but that only works against properties and fields, which makes sense considering they're the only things that should influence serialization.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: I'm not familiar with XNA, but if you remove Texture2D from consideration, how can `Load<Texture2D>` succeed without raising an exception? Your question is fairly clear but it's not clear how your example relates to it. I would say however that serialisation does have to look at generic types, because otherwise it can't be guaranteed to be able to reconstruct whatever it reads from the stream.

Comment: Calling `Load<Texture2D>` works if the reflective reader hasn't got in there first and claimed that it is reponsible for loading textures. If, for example, I skip the call to load my test level then the texture successfully loads using XNA's `TextureReader` or whatever it's called. I dispute that the generic parameters have any bearing on serialization. Serialization concerns itself only with the state of an object, and the object in question has no entity in it. The generic parameter is only used in methods on the object, not in data.

Comment: @user13414, serialisation needs to know exactly what kind of object it is in order to recreate it at the other end - there will be constructors to call, for example. And the type of the object includes the specific argument passed as a generic parameter, at least in languages like C# and C++ (maybe not in Java, which implements generics somewhat differently).

Comment: @Kylotan: the base class is generic, not the subclass (which is the object being serialized). It is a closed generic type, not an open one.

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference. Serialisation is implemented via reflection, and the reflective data for TestEntityData includes a class which itself includes references to Texture2D, even though you don't serialise it. (You might get more info here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx)

Comment: @Kylotan: if I gave you an instance of TestEntityData and asked you to serialize it so it could later be rehydrated, all you'd need to store is the type and the values of its public properties. You don't care about any generic types in its hierarchy - it's completely irrelevant unless the public properties expose members including those generic type parameters.

Comment: You're missing the point - this isn't about serialisation, it's about reflection. It is possible, in some languages, to serialise objects without needing to know every type in its hierarchy, but reflection Does need to know these things - and XNA implements serialisation via reflection, hence the name ReflectiveReader.

Comment: @Kylotan: sorry, but you're wrong. Every type in the hierarchy does not need to be known. Only the base type. If I had typeof(TestData) I could call Activator.CreateInstance with that type. At serialization time, there is no need for any knowledge of types in the hierarchy, be they generic or not. At runtime, there is no extra information required regarding the generic types because TestData is a closed generic type, not an open one. Seriously, this is a few lines of code to demonstrate. I would update my question, but it seems superfluous.

Comment: The docs I linked to state that .NET reflection stores information about the generic types regarding their type parameters, and this can be obtained via `Type.GetGenericArguments`, whether a closed generic type or an open generic type. Maybe the docs are wrong and you are right, but the docs explain why Texture2D is covered by the Reflection system and hence show up in your serialisation code. Maybe you could ask on MSDN since it doesn't seem anybody here has a better idea.

Comment: did you lookat this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428398/loading-textures-from-a-reference-to-built-content-in-an-xml-file

Answer (score 4):

While it's true that *in general*, serialization doesn't necessarily have to concern itself with the types of the objects in question and only record representations of their state... not all serialization implementations do that. Most of the built-in .NET serialization methods *do* record information about types participating in serialization. There are advantages to that choice (allowing for more robust validation) as well as disadvantages (larger serialized object size), but it's not *wrong* per se and you just have to live with it.

XNA's content pipeline, for your types, traverses the serializable property (and field) graph and creates readers for them. You can see this behavior if you examine the initialization for `ReflectiveReader<T>` (the `Initialize` method, not the constructor). It does this via reflection, *not* based on the actual data in the XML (again, this is verifiable by looking at the reflected code). So it doesn't matter if there is a reference to the texture in your data or not, if there's a `Texture2D` property in the type's property graph, it will try to create a reader for it as part of the initialization of the content pipeline.

You are not supposed to use direct references to `Texture2D` objects in your custom content. You may find [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910020641/http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/96662.aspx) (or [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910020549/http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/44917.aspx), to a lesser degree). The alleged solution to the issue is to use external references to `Texture2DContent` instead.